Meaning of "I opened the door and reached for the light switch just inside."
I read this sentence from the book "Let's Get Invisible" by R.L Stine:

I opened the door and reached for the light switch just inside.

I don't completely understand the meaning of "just inside". According to Longman dictionary one of the usages of "just" is:

only by a small amount, time, distance etc
just before/after/over etc
We moved here just after our son was born.
I saw her just before she died.
It’s just under three centimetres long.

According to this usage, the person opened the door and moved his arm in order to touch the light switch very close to inside of the room. But the fact that the light switch is very close to "inside of the room" doesn't make a lot of sense to me.

Light switches are often placed on the wall close to the doorway so you don't have to walk into a dark room in order to turn on a light.
So "just inside (the room)" alludes to the fact that you can reach into the room with your arm and flip the switch. You don't have to take even a single stride.
P.S. inside can refer to  a simple binary opposition: not outside. But since the space of a room is three-dimensional, "inside" also admits the notion of degree:

They were deep inside the cave.

And "just" does not mean "close to".  It refers to a small extent or degree.  So it's not "close to inside" but to-a-small-extent inside the three-dimensional space of the room.

It means that the light-switch is just inside the doorway. Which almost goes without saying.
From the perspective of the person, that is also "just inside the room".

Goes without saying? I would expect this figure of speech to be confusing to a learner, since "inside X" normally mesans "within the perimeter of X," and in this sense the switch is not "inside the door." This answer could be improved by pointing the OP toward a supporting dictionary, like entry 1b under preposition here: "on the inner side of
(just inside the door)"
